# Add firebase cloud function in existing project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a project which contains Firebase and already runs. Today I need to add cloud functions inside. But I don't know how to add it in a running project. I didn't find proper documents for my case.

What would happened if I tried `init firebase` and checked cloud functions only in my current project. Will it delete my previous setup (i have installed Firestore, storage,etc)?
[image: fireabse]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained in the Firebase CLI [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#initialize_a_firebase_project), "you can always run `firebase init` later to set up more Firebase products" after the initial initialization.

So, running it again will not delete your previous setup.

---

Take care to only select the additional services: as noted in the doc, "If you run `firebase init` again for any Firebase service, the command will overwrite the corresponding section of the `firebase.json` file back to the default configuration for that service."

Comment: So, if i just check 'function'. Firebase storage still exist right? And other dependency in package.json

Comment: "So, if i just check 'function'. Firebase storage still exist?" => Yes. Of course you can make a backup of the directory before :-)

Comment: thank you... am really noob for this, and little bit nervous to make changes